# What is the difference with _se maps in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've noticed that in CS:GO, there are two versions of some maps: The "normal" map, and the _se version of the map (for instance, de_aztec and de_aztec_se).

What is the difference between the standard map and the _se version of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**_se** maps doesn't have chickens, breakable items (like the flowers and paintings that can be shoot to pieces or down) and weather effects.

Some players associate it as either Silent Edition or Second Edition

Comment: Along with this, they are typically geared towards competitive play with several changes made from the original. Leagues like ESEA have used the SE version of maps in the past prior to Valve changing their maps with similar changes.

Comment: Less random factor (like chickens ruining grenade throws) = better competitive value.

Comment: "SE" refers to "simplified edition" according to the [CS:GO Steam Workshop account](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198082857351/myworkshopfiles/?appid=730), for example [Inferno_se](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=125499116).

Comment: @user598527 Then write your own answer for that. Don't edit someone else's answer to change what it says; that's not what edits are for.

Comment: @user1306322: At least currently, [hitting a chicken doesn't affect grenade trajectory](https://youtu.be/syCN8sF0ulo?t=3m35s). Also applies to bombs and blocked weapons, and there is no player collision either.

Answer (score 2):

`_se` refers to "simplified edition" according to the [CS:GO Steam Workshop account](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198082857351/myworkshopfiles/?appid=730) ([official collection of `_se` maps](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=125499590) for easier access, may not include all maps).